# mongoose db returning data from two documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating my first mongoose database app.  I am trying to write an express API call that returns an object that contains data from two documents.  Whenever I call the /data route I get an empty array back.  I added two console.log lines and the output is:

```
test2
test1
```

What can I do to have the forEach finish before returning the result?

Here's the code:

```
router.route('/data')
//get all data
.get(function(req, res) {
    var results = [];
    Attendee.find(function(err, attendees) {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}
        else {
            attendees.forEach(function(attendee) {

                Message.find({userID: attendee._id}, function(err,messages){
                    results.push({
                        attendee: attendee,
                        messages: messages
                    });
                });
                console.log("test1");
                console.log(results);
            });
            console.log("test2");
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the result I would like to get

```
[ { attendee: 
 { _id: 53c060e7fb90e3d709d6bdae,
   fullName: ‘joe smith,
   phoneNumber: '+555’,
   __v: 0 },
messages: 
 [ { _id: 53c06887fb1d24fb095fd365,
     phoneNumber: '+555',
     body: ‘test’,
     userID: '53c060e7fb90e3d709d6bdae',
     sid: 'SMa86f2914986d4b04067d7f054da205a5',
     __v: 0 },
   { _id: 53c41cf3d068393d17dc0dbf,
     phoneNumber: '+555',
     body: ‘test’,
     userID: '53c060e7fb90e3d709d6bdae',
     sid: 'SM4f6c64ca7b39e6caee9859e761a2850d',
     __v: 0 },
   { _id: 53c421e16371e54f171751cf,
     phoneNumber: '+555',
     body: ‘test’,
     userID: '53c060e7fb90e3d709d6bdae',
     sid: 'SM1097eae33e4f53cdcdad32651c016437',
     __v: 0 },
   { _id: 53c421e16371e54f171751d0,
     phoneNumber: '+555',
     body: ‘test’,
     userID: '53c060e7fb90e3d709d6bdae',
     sid: 'SM5a452e51c995d7ad6ad8f7b85cec80b0',
     __v: 0 } ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that you are sending back the results in the response before they have been fully retrieved.  Your `res.json(results)` is outside the `Message.find(...)` callback.  Additionally, since you push the attendee object onto the results array in that same callback, it too will be missing, and your returned results array will simply be the original empty array.

You need something more like this:

```
router.route('/data')
//get all data
.get(function(req, res) {
    var results = [];
    Attendee.find(function(err, attendees) {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}
        else {
            q.all(attendees.map(function(attendee) {
                return Message
                    .find({userID: attendee._id}, "")
                    .exec()
                    .then(function(messages) {
                        results.push({
                            attendee: attendee,
                            messages: messages
                        });         
                     })
            }))
            .then(function() {
                res.json(results);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ah yes, but this will return the results after the first iteration of the forEach loop.  What if I have multiple attendees? (which I very much plan to have)

Comment: You're right of course, edited answer.  It uses Q though, a promise library: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by using a mongoose feature called populate.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.  I was able to simplify my code a lot:

```
    router.route('/data')
    //get all data
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Attendee.find().populate('messages').exec(function(err, attendees){
            if (err) {res.send(err);}
            res.json(attendees);
        });
    });
```

The real magic of this code is in the schemes:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var AttendeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    dateJoined: {
        type: Date,
        require: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    messages: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Message"
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Attendee', AttendeeSchema);
```

and

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userID: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Attendee'
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        require: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```